# How to place two labels around an image (dynamically); right and bottom?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, layout

I'm generating a visual list of search results, and I want to format it as such:

[image: Valid XHTML].

I'm not sure how to do this. Here's what it currently looks like

[image: Valid Xhtml].

Here's the code for the web form that I am placing these results in

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Search.</h2>
<div class="searchblock" id="searchdiv" runat="server">

    <asp:Button id="TestSearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search the Stuff" OnClick="TestSearchButton_Click" CssClass="btn-default" />

    <asp:TextBox ID="EnterBox" runat="server" Text="Hittin NM"/>

    <hr/>

    <div id="searchResults" runat="server">
    </div>
</div>
```

The results are getting placed in the 'searchResults' div.

Here's the code that I use to generate these result blocks

```
while (i <= allmantemp.Count - 1)
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.CssClass = "ResultPanel";

    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img2 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    panel.Controls.Add(img2);
    img2.CssClass = "DisplayedImage";
    img2.ImageUrl = "Resources/allmanmushroom.jpg";

    Label numberBox = new Label();
    panel.Controls.Add(numberBox);
    numberBox.CssClass = "ItemNumberResult";
    numberBox.Text = "Item #:" + allmantemp[i].itemNum.ToString();

    Label titleBox = new Label();
    titleBox.CssClass = "ItemTitleResult";
    titleBox.Text = allmantemp[i].title;

    Label descriptionBox = new Label();
    descriptionBox.CssClass = "DescriptionResult";
    descriptionBox.Text = allmantemp[i].description;

    panel.Controls.Add(numberBox);
    panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    panel.Controls.Add(titleBox);
    panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    panel.Controls.Add(descriptionBox);
    searchResults.Controls.Add(panel);

    i++;

}
```

And here are the CSS classes referenced

```
.DisplayedImage{
height: 180px;
width: 180px;
padding-top: initial;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-right: 6px;
margin-left: 6px;
float: left;
}

.ResultPanel{    
margin-left: 210px;
width: auto;
height: 200px;
display: block;
border: solid;
border-color: #DFECE6;
}

.ItemNumberResult{
background-color: #2D2D29;
color: #DFECE6;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-top: 10px; 
width: 180px;
}

.ItemTitleResult{
background-color: #2D2D29;
color: #DFECE6;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-top: 10px; 
width: 180px;
}
```

I know the code I have given is will produce the second result; but I have no idea how to make the layout look like I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating and clearing `.ItemNumberResult` should move it below the image and let the other content stay up on the right.

```
.ItemNumberResult{
    background-color: #2D2D29;
    color: #DFECE6;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: This works; but now there's a large space between the item # label and the border of the panel, and I've removed the bottom margin
EDIT: I'm dumb it was because I forgot to change the height of the panel.

Comment: ;) not dumb, we all do that sometimes